How to prevent output exponential number in seaborn graphic?
I have a data visualization task. My maximum values is 1,000,000. When I plot the data the y-axis labels are displayed in exponential notation (1.13811e+06) which I do not like. I want to display the full numeric value without the exponential format.
I've tried plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y'), but it doesn't work for me:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [1000000, 2000000, 3000000, 4000000, 5000000]
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')
plt.xlabel('X-axis')
plt.ylabel('Y-axis')
plt.title('Plot title')
plt.show()

